# Push updates to multipe remote servers (Ubuntu)

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I would like to be able to push updates of files to remote servers running Ubuntu.

I'm not sure how to go about explaining this but hopefully this example will help:
[image: Example image]

Is there any software that would be able to do this or would it be possible to do this with a bash script?

I would also need to be able to execute shell commands before and after the file updates as I am using it as a kind of instant messaging server which will need to be stopped and started.

I hope this is clear enough, I honestly have no idea how to explain this.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rsync http://rsync.samba.org/ may help you to synchronize your files and inotify https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki could also be used to watch file changes.

Comment: I have looked at rsync but not sure how I would use it to update files on multiple servers and run shell commands. Perhaps use a bash script on each server? Then I would need a way to trigger it.

Comment: No you should run it only from your main server. It must only be able to connect remote servers and access the directory (via SSH by instance)

Answer (score 0):

You may try using "puppet" to automate deployment and configuration from the central server: http://puppetlabs.com/

Comment: I have looked at puppet but I'm not sure that it's what I want. Is there a good example somewhere on how it can be used?

Comment: Please take a look on [Example](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90015/how-to-copy-files-to-all-machines-using-puppet-master) and [Puppet Essentials](http://example42.com/tutorials/build/deck/essentials/) - hope that helps)